# Request.QueryString returns a value only twice. [ASP, JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I am creating a reservation program where the test2.asp page returns the result according to the date sent from the test1.asp page. I don't know where I'm doing wrong, but it only returns 2x result. It doesn't matter if I add or subtract the value. It always returns the correct result only 2 times and then stops.

Page test1.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeOfmonth(posun) {
        var monNum = Number($("#monCal").val());
        var yearNum = Number($("#yearCal").val());
        if (posun == 1) { $("#monCal").val(monNum + 1) };
        if (posun == 2) { $("#monCal").val(monNum - 1) };

        if ($("#monCal").val() == 13) {
            $("#yearCal").val(yearNum + 1);
            $("#monCal").val(1);
        };

        if ($("#monCal").val() == 0) {
            $("#yearCal").val(yearNum - 1);
            $("#monCal").val(12);
        };
        var sendKal = $("#monCal").val() + ',' + $("#yearCal").val();
        $.get('test2.asp?sendMonYear=' + sendKal, function (vystup) {
            $("#testResult").html(vystup);
        })
    }

</script>

     <div style="width:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
         <input name="butMon1" onclick="changeOfmonth(2);" type="button" id="plusMonth" value="&#8592;" />
         <input name="butMon3" onclick="changeOfmonth(1);" type="button" id="minusMonth" value="&#8594;" />
    </div>

    <input id="monCal" type="text" value="7" /><input id="yearCal" type="text" value="2022" /><br/>
    <div id="testResult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page test2.asp

```
<% response.write "<br> Result: " & Request.QueryString("sendMonYear") %>
```

Comment: Double entry for data like that means the loop went through and on the 2nd pass added the data when it only needed to add it once.   Can you pass that data to the end result without looping again?

Comment: Also your problem is with Javascript and not Asp Classic by the way.

Comment: Where is your <form method="get" action="test2.asp"> segment?  Its got an input but no <form> or </form> ... hmm you are just using buttons to pass the data along ... without the form method="get"  i don't think it is able to pass the data properly, unless your second page has some correction code to allow for this?

Comment: Also of note .. those 2 buttons .. they will run the function when you click them, but their value being passed is "&#8594;" for both buttons  , some js could make that work I'm sure, but normally you pass  some kind of calculated value to the next page.  But in reality you are passing it to the URL instead of a page, and the 2nd page is just reading that URL.  If you want to do form to page stuff you want method ="POST" vs method="GET" like you are using now.

Comment: I think <form> is not needed for this method. Instead, it is used: $.get('test2.asp?sendMonYear='.  More information here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I see you are passing it to  jquery api.  What is the result you get?  You say you get 2x the result .. is it the same result two times in a row?   I guess you only click which button you want to get the result?  One takes a month away, the other adds a month?  You do click the buttons though or is it auto submit?  If its auto submit, its clicking both buttons and giving you both results one month before and after at the same time?  But im just guessing without knowing the actual result you are getting.

Comment: :-o  so now I don't understand it anymore. I have tried uploading the pages (test1.asp, test2.asp) to another web server and it works there. http://cyklobotanika.cz/test/test1.asp

Comment: Hmm .. without seeing the error message I am not sure, but if a different host worked, then it might be a setting on the original web server perhaps?  Are you able to keep it at the new location as a solution or do you need it to work in the original location still?

Comment: my hosting provider has already fixed this problem. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: In case one record is a problem like being NULL, try adding "On Error Resume Next" in your loop.